# Error related to misunderstanding of memory management concept?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create my own class to manage matrixes, but I'm a newbie with Objective-C.

Matrix class
I'm creating this class to manage matrices saving it in a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArray`'s.

```
@interface matrix : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableArray *grid;

    // Dimensiones de la matriz.
    NSUInteger num_columns;
    NSUInteger num_rows;

}
```

I created a method to add rows, columns and other operations. The method addRow is like this:

```
-(BOOL) addRow:(NSArray *) fila
{
    NSLog(@"Dentro de Añadir una Fila de una matriz.");

    [grid addObject:fila];

    [self checkDimensions];

    return YES;
}
```

I use a method of an `extern` class. The method is so easy because I only want to create a matrix and print it.

```
-(BOOL) matrixTEST
{
    NSLog(@"Dentro de Testeo de una matriz.");

    // create a new instance
    matrix *m = [[matrix alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *vector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [vector addObject:@"1"];
    [vector addObject:@"2"];
    [vector addObject:@"3"];
    [m addRow:vector];    
    [vector removeAllObjects];
    [vector addObject:@"4"];
    [vector addObject:@"5"];
    [vector addObject:@"6"];
    [m addRow:vector];
    [vector removeAllObjects];
    [vector addObject:@"7"];
    [vector addObject:@"8"];
    [vector addObject:@"3"];
    [m addRow:vector];
    [vector removeAllObjects];;

    // print matriz
    [m imprimirMatriz];

    [vector release];
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is I don't know what I am doing wrong because method printMatrix shows an error of bad access or zeros. Also, the vars defined to contain number of rows and columns show weird values: `- Rows : 5.75753e+228  - Columns : 8.55507e-53`

Method to print Matrix.

```
-(void) imprimirMatriz
{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // NSNumber *numero = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Dentro de imprimir matriz.");

    [self printDimensions];

    for(NSUInteger c = 0; c < num_rows; c++)
    {
        temp = [grid objectAtIndex:c];

        for(NSUInteger d = 0; d < num_columns; d++)
        {
            NSLog(@" %3g ", [temp objectAtIndex:d]);
        }
        NSLog(@"\n");
    }

    [temp release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `-(BOOL) matrixTest` you insert strings. This is perfectly fine. But when you print the values in your grid array, you specify "%3g". "%g" prints, as far as I remember, a float or a double, and will not work when your values are strings. If you substitute %g with %@, it should work.

Regarding the variables containing width and height of array: you have not provided your implementation of how you set these variables, so it is impossible to know what the problem is.

As a side note, you have some other errors as well. in `-(void) imprimirMatriz` you have the line `NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, but you later on assign `temp` to something else. This causes a memory leak. Alloc/init is not neccessary when you assign a variable to something from an NSArray.

As an answer to your comment: you can only insert objects into an NSMutableArray (or NSArray for that sake). When you write `[myArray addObject:1]`, you try to insert a primitive integer. Primitives (int, bool, char, float, double and so on) are not objects, and therefore cannot be inserted into an NSArray or NSMutableArray. Instead, you can insert an int by wrapping it in an instance of NSNumber. The following line will work: `[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];`. You can also have floats and other types in an NSNumber object. See [NSNumber Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a full reference.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But another questions. I want to insert numbers (float) instead of strings in the array. But when i write something in the init method without @" " obtain a warning message.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a new array for each row in your test function - otherwise you are adding a pointer to the same object three times, removing all of the objects and re-filling. I expect by the end of the above code you have three copies of the same empty array in your matrix.

So, instead of

```
[m addRow:vector];         
[vector removeAllObjects]; // This removes the objects from the array in your matrix as well!
```

Do

```
[m addRow:vector];
[vector release];
vector = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The last `removeAllObjects` will empty the array (and so empty every row in your matrix) but not update your internal dimension variables, so is likely to lead to errors later on.

In addition, as Bendik says, your log statement is in the wrong format for strings. It should be %@